# Iterate through pagenumbers in URL - Python Curl API

Tags: python, json, api, loops, curl

I want to fetch all incoming calls trough an API and save them into a JSON-File.

The API provides only 100 calls per page.

I need to iterate through the pages in the URL

```
ApiRequestCallCenterDaily = requests.get('https://api.placetel.de/v2/call_center_calls?date=2020-04-01&page=1&per_page=100', params={
'date': '2020-04-14'}, 
headers=headers)
```

i need to loop trough this part till x
`page=1`

```
After that i write the JSON-Object into a JSON-File to upload it to S3
DailyJsonFileForCallCenterCalls = open("call_center_calls_daily.json", "a")
print(ApiRequestCallCenterDaily.json(), file=DailyJsonFileForCallCenterCalls)
DailyJsonFileForCallCenterCalls.close()
```

I'm not a developer, so I'm seeking a short explanation, how to iterate trough X pages.

I've tried different solutions, but I don't understand my mistakes.

Comment: Pay attention for `Python` name convention! that `variables` should not start with `uppercase` letter!

Comment: I'll change that !

Comment: Welcome! If I understand correctly, and you want to change the string "page=1" 100 times to iterate from 1 to 100, you should look up Python string and string concatenation.

Comment: I want to change to the pages from 1 to 10 and safe everything in the same JSON-File.
I'll take a look at your proposals. 
Thanks !

Comment: @CLi check below answer, within the loop of `(1, 101)` you can change it to `(1, 11)` so it's will start by `1` and end by `10`

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests

params = {
    'date': '2020-04-01',
    'per_page': '100'
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for item in range(1, 101):
            params['page'] = item
            r = req.get(url, params=params).json()
            with open("data.json", 'a') as f:
                f.write(r)


main("https://api.placetel.de/v2/call_center_calls")
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this out !